# Changing from Navlist Panel to tabPanels in Shiny

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

[image: snapshot from Application]I have a shiny Application which has a navigation List to the Left , I am having issues with the User Interface file in which i try to change the Navigation list to tabsets , But the below code does it for all the entire tabs that are present in shiny , But i want to choose a specific side tab in this case "Word Network " and want plot1 and plot 2 coded below should be shown only in this navigation and not other .

```
navlistPanel(
   tabPanel("Introduction", 
       fluidRow(h3("Introduction",align="center"),tags$img(src="TextAnalytics.jpg",height=300,width=600),align="center"),
        value=11,verbatimTextOutput("introduction")),
        #tags$img(src="TextAnalytics.jpg",height=800,width=800),

        tabPanel("Upload the File",fileInput("data1",label=("Upload the Unstructured Textual data To be analysed"))),
        tabPanel("structure",value=1,verbatimTextOutput("str")),
        tabPanel("data",value=2,tableOutput("data")),
        tabPanel("Summary",value=3,verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
        tabPanel("Word Cloud",value=4,plotOutput("plot",width=1000,height=600)),
        tabPanel("Sentiment Analysis",value=5,plotOutput("plot2",width=1000,height=600)),
        tabPanel("Topic Modelling",value=6,plotOutput("plot3",width=1000,height=600)),
        #tabPanel("Word Frequency",value=7,plotOutput("plot4",width=1000,height=800)),
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("plot1",value = 11),
          tabPanel("plot2",value = 11)
        ),
        tabPanel("Hierarchial Clustering",value=8,plotOutput("graph1",width=1500,height=h)),
        tabPanel("Correlation Analysis",value=9,plotOutput("corelation",width=1000,height=1000)),
        tabPanel("Word Network",value=10,plotOutput("graph2",width=1000,height=600)),
        tabPanel("Community Detection",value=12,plotOutput("democommunity",width=1000,height=600)),
        id="tabselected"
   )
)
```

Comment: Try creating a toy small application (that can stand alone without data -or just with fake data) that does what you want, and if you can't get that to work, post that as your question with a screen shot. You get way faster answers that way, and learn more too.

Comment: Thank you Mike , I have added a screenshot in which multiple navigation lists are there, and i want plot 1 and plot 2 should only be active when i select the navigation of word network and not other ,